# How to display output after applying the watershed algoithm?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, watershed

I have applied watershed algorithm to segment characters of an ancient writing. Now How to get the segmented characters as output?

I am working on segmenting characters from ancient inscriptions to build an OCR. I have tried MATLAB before but I am not getting sufficient results. Then I learnt about watershed algorithm, got this code from their documentation. I applied the code, It runs but doesn't output anything.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Load image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('templegs.png',0)

kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(opening,(1,1),0)
ret3,th4 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# sure background area
sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening,kernel,iterations=1)
# Finding sure foreground area
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.DIST_L2,3)
dist_transform = np.uint8(dist_transform)
ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.7*dist_transform.max(),255,0)
sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg,sure_fg)

ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)
markers = markers+1
markers[unknown==255] = 0
markers = markers.astype('int32')

#now load same image as color image
img = cv2.imread('temple.jpg',1)

markers = cv2.watershed(img,markers)
img[markers == -1] = [255,0,0]
```

I expect an image output.

Comment: imshow is your friend

Comment: Can you share an example input image?